# DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'o_id'

Tags: asp.net, gridview

```
when I am trying to bind data to GridView in asp.net it shows the error     "DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the   name 'o_id'..". can anyone one please help me. 

this is my database table fields: 
         o_id int primary key identity(1,1),
         o_date nvarchar(20) ,
         o_time nvarchar(20),

        name_project nvarchar(60),
```

.aspx page

```
  <asp:GridView ID="GvProj" runat="server"  AllowPaging="True"   CssClass="AllGrid" 
        PagerStyle-CssClass="pgrAll"  DataKeyNames="o_id">
        <PagerStyle CssClass="pgrAll"></PagerStyle>
      <RowStyle BackColor="#ffffff" ForeColor="#000000"    />
     <HeaderStyle BackColor="#4a70d0" ForeColor="#ffffff"  />
     <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#c0c0c0"   ForeColor="#000000"FontSize="14px" />
    </asp:GridView>
```

**.cs file**

cmd.CommandText = "select o_id as ID,o_date as DATE,name_project as NAME from OrderManagement ";

```
                int count = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();



                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                da.Fill(dt);
                GvProj.DataSource = dt;
                GvProj.DataBind();
                GvProj.Visible = true;
                GvInvidual.Visible = false;
```

Comment: where are you binding your db columns to gridview?

Comment: i just want to select database data from my table named "OrderManagement" and want to display in a gridview named "GvProj".

Comment: but when  i give DatakeyName in gridview property its not working. otherwise it works

Comment: for that you need to bind those DB rows to the aspx gridview markup

Comment: try to give ID in datakeynames

Comment: sir , can you please explain.. because i am fresher....

Comment: try this DataKeyNames="ID" in the markup

Comment: yes.. it works...I gave DatakeyName as "ID" instead of o_id...now it works...thank u so much  Mr.Webruster ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your DB name for the o_ID is `ID` Because you are not retrieving the same and trying to change that column with alias Name. so try changing like this:

```
DataKeyNames="ID"
```